# How to avoid Too Many SOQL Queries

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits

I know that the reason for this it's because I have a query that it's executed inside a loop, but I don't see how to redesign the code to avoid this. Any help will be appreciated.

Basically, I have a scheduled class that queries cases with certain criteria and checks if they have a public article attached, if the article is public, then an email should be sent to the case contact.

This is part of my scheduled class code.

```
public void sendKBArticle(){

     Boolean hasPublicArticles;
     Id EmailTemplateId='00XP0000000MHPI'; 

     Map<id,case> cMap = new Map<id,case>(
     [Select Id,ContactId from Case   Where Owner.Type='User' AND IsClosed=false AND KB_Article_Sent__c=false 
         AND Status NOT IN ('Pending Bug Fix','Solution Provided','Escalated','Reopened')
             AND RecordType.Name IN ('Internal', 'Customer Portal') AND CreatedDate  = LAST_N_DAYS:3 ]);

        if(!cMap.IsEmpty()){

           for(Case cnt : cMap.values()) {

                ArticlePublicLinksonEmail cpkb=new ArticlePublicLinksonEmail();

                hasPublicArticles=cpkb.getPublicArticles(cnt.id);

                if(hasPublicArticles){

                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setTemplateId(EmailTemplateId);
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(cnt.ContactId);
                    mail.setWhatId(cnt.Id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);  
                    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                    Cnt.KB_Article_Sent__c=true;
                }
            }

           try {
                 update cMap.values();
           } catch (DMLException e){         

                .....some code
           }
        }
     }    
}
```

As you can see, inside the loop I am passing the object id to another method, this method uses this case id to query if the case has a public article attached. Therefore, if I have many cases I hit the query limit.

Any ideas how to fix this or any suggestions in how to approach this in a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Rewrite getPublicArticles to accept a list/set of caseids and return a map of ids+integer/boolean instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Exception: Too many SOQL queries: 101](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/system-exception-too-many-soql-queries-101)

Comment: Pepefloyd maybe you could rephrase around how to bulkify this type of secnario ?

Comment: @ChristianDeckert This post is 2 years old...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@MartinPeters is on the right track: `getPublicArticles` needs to work in bulk somehow. You need to call `getPublicArticles` outside of the loop, since it's doing a query every time. So collect Case Ids before the `getPublicArticles` and loop through the results to deal with public articles afterward.

Also, you are calling `Messaging.sendEmail()` inside your loop, which will also hit the governor limit eventually. Instead, keep a running `list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>`, and do `Messaging.sendEmail()` once the list is full.

```
set<Id> caseids = cMap.keyset();
//assuming this method is "private map<Id, Boolean> getPublicArticles(set<Id> caseids)"
map<Id, Boolean> caseid2HasPublicArticlesmap = getPublicArticles(caseids);

list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailstosend = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(Case cnt : cMap.values()) {
    if (caseid2HasPublicArticlesmap.get(cnt.Id) == TRUE) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                mail.setTemplateId(EmailTemplateId);
                mail.setTargetObjectId(cnt.ContactId);
                mail.setWhatId(cnt.Id);
                mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);  
                //Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
                emailstosend.add(mail);
                Cnt.KB_Article_Sent__c=true;
    }
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emailstosend);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, this seems to be the right approach. I am struggling to convert the getPublicArticles method to "BULK MODE", I will keep trying but I might need to come back for additional help : S

Comment: I was able to create this method and get this working as suggested. Thanks again!